# Python - How to sum a certain section of a list

Tags: python, list, sum

I have a list of 90 values and I would like to find the value of the sum of the first 30 of these values. Is there a way I can do this easily?

Comment: `total = 0; for i in range(30): total += values[i]` works...

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following command:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5.....90]
s = sum(l[:30])
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest would be to just slice it:

```
result = sum(lst[0:30])
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to do is slice the list and use sum function

```
ans = sum(input[:30])
```

If you want to add numbers between a particular range let's say you want to add numbers between 20-30(inclusive) then you can do that as

```
ans = sum(input[20:31])
```